# SSJS Activities : Move Data Extentions in a Folder

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, dataextensions, ssjs, folder

I'm investigating the SSJS activities. I'm not a JavaScript programmer but I'm trying to learn. Now I have managed to create Date Extension, a Create a folder path. Now I would like to be able to write (in the same script or a new one) a script that takes a Date Extension and move it to a folder.
How do I implement this?

At the moment I'm trying to test this code, but it does not work.

```
<script runat=server>

Platform.Load("core","1");

var FolderScript= Folder.Retrieve({Property:"Name",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:"Folder Script"});
var FolderScriptID = FolderScript[0].ID;

var DEscript= DataExtension.Init("ScriptDE20");
DEscript.setFolderId(FolderScriptID);

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [DataExtension SSJS](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/core_library_server_side_javascript_functions/data_extension_server_side_javascript_functions/) function for moving DataExtension one folder to another and pass the destination folder id.

```
<script runat=server>

Platform.Load("core","1");

var updateDE = DataExtension.Init('demoDE'); //DE ExternalKey 
var newFolder = {
    CategoryID : "95232" // FolderID
};
var myDE = updateDE.Update(newFolder);
Write(myDE);

</script>
```

**Result:** OK

Comment: I have problem in the line :
var myDE = updateDE.Update(newField);

Maybe the right way is : 

var myDE = updateDE.Update(newFolder);

Also in this case doesn't work !

Comment: It should work, you just need to change the DE ExternalKey and FolderID in above code.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the code. 
Why did you insert "newField" in the Update(...) ? and why did you creare an object " newFolder" ? I think that in this way I am not able to pass the destination folder id.

Comment: I think it's a mistake. In fact, I am changing the names I was able to do this thing.

Comment: I have updated my code.

Answer (score 2):

This the right code to achieve my requirement:

```
<script runat=server>

Platform.Load("core","1");

var FolderScript= Folder.Retrieve({Property:"Name",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:"Folder Script"});
var FolderScriptID = FolderScript[0].ID;

var updateDE = DataExtension.Init('ScriptDE20'); //DE ExternalKey 

var newField = {
        "CategoryID" : FolderScriptID // FolderID
    };

var myDE = updateDE.Update(newField);
Write(myDE);

</script>
```