# Data Extensions folder in Marketing Cloud getting crowded - can I bulk move them to subfolders?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

We've been using Marketing Cloud in my organisation now for nearly a year. As we send about 20 email sends a day we have roughly 3,200 data extensions sitting in our master Data Extensions folder. We have set up subfolders to move them into but have not really been following this protocol. The subfolders are named after a certain component of the job number string - for example there's a Data Extension called

```
TCA_00001_PAD_B80_01
```

And we have a subfolder called

```
PAD
```

I'd like to be able to move all data extensions which contain the string `*_PAD_*` into the PAD subfolder.

Using the Search box in the Data Extension folder to search for a DE only works if you search from the beginning of the name - so I'd find my job if I searched for `TCA_` but wouldn't find it if I searched for `_PAD_`.

Does anyone know of another way I could do this without manually moving DEs around?

Comment: This could be done via API calls.  But, may not be an option depending due to the necessary learning curve.

Comment: Since you are already using SSJS for existing data upload, check this link if you can use for moving DE: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/139763/ssjs-activities-move-data-extentions-in-a-folder